# How can this linux question have so many windows only answers

Tags: discussion

I found this question when searching for information [Bower: ENOGIT Git is not installed or not in the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20666989/1542723)

> Git is installed and is in the path.
>
> Platform: Red Hat Linux 5.8.
>
> ```
> >which git
> /usr/local/bin/git
> ```
>
> Yet bower can't find it:
>
> ```
> bower angular#1.0.6  ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
> ```
>
> What is the recommended work-around?

However, most answers are clearly about a windows platform, and despite that they were still upvoted instead of flagged as "Not an answer", causing confusing when thinking you found your problem when the answers are unclear.

---

Should we edit the question to point to a generic platform?

Or should we instead hold a mass answer nuking party?

Comment: A Windows programmer is likely to know what "Git" and "Path" means.  But unlikely to know what RHEL might be, other than that release hell is suffered universally.  The acronym didn't get spelled-out until almost two years later.  Tagging [linux] would have been wise perhaps.